# MySQL - calculate percent of a column with multiple column grouping

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
desc test;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dept   | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sub    | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary | int(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

select * from test;
+------+-----------+------+------+--------+
| id   | name      | dept | sub  | salary |
+------+-----------+------+------+--------+
|    1 | Rishabh   | A    | X    |    150 |
|    2 | Manish    | B    | Y    |    120 |
|    3 | Sachin    | A    | Z    |    160 |
|    4 | Abhiskhek | C    | Z    |    100 |
|    5 | Manan     | B    | Z    |    170 |
|    6 | Rahul     | C    | X    |    150 |
|    7 | Rohan     | C    | Y    |    120 |
|    8 | Mukul     | B    | Z    |    110 |
|    9 | Lalit     | B    | X    |    130 |
+------+-----------+------+------+--------+
```

So far I am able to do percent of a single column group

```
select dept, sum(salary), round(sum(salary)*100/t.s,2) as `perc` 
from test cross join (select sum(salary) as s from test) t group by dept;
```

which yields the following:

```
+------+-------------+-------+
| dept | sum(salary) | perc  |
+------+-------------+-------+
| A    |         310 | 25.62 |
| B    |         530 | 43.80 |
| C    |         370 | 30.58 |
+------+-------------+-------+
```

so now I have another column to group by, I made the query,

```
select dept, sub, sum(salary), round(sum(salary)*100/t.s) as `perc` 
from test cross join (select sum(salary) as s from test) t group by dept,sub;
```

which output the following:

```
+------+------+-------------+-------+
| dept | sub  | sum(salary) | perc  |
+------+------+-------------+-------+
| A    | X    |         150 | 12.40 |
| A    | Z    |         160 | 13.22 |
| B    | X    |         130 | 10.74 |
| B    | Y    |         120 |  9.92 |
| B    | Z    |         280 | 23.14 |
| C    | X    |         150 | 12.40 |
| C    | Y    |         120 |  9.92 |
| C    | Z    |         100 |  8.26 |
+------+------+-------------+-------+
```

it is making the relevant row percentage from the total sum = `select sum(salary) from test;`
but I expect it to show percent from it's respective group only, (in this case percent of sub's salary from total dept salary)

Expected output:

```
+------+------+-------------+-------+
| dept | sub  | sum(salary) | perc  |
+------+------+-------------+-------+
| A    | X    |         150 | 48.39 |
| A    | Z    |         160 | 51.61 |
| B    | X    |         130 | 24.53 |
| B    | Y    |         120 | 22.64 |
| B    | Z    |         280 | 52.83 |
| C    | X    |         150 | 40.54 |
| C    | Y    |         120 | 32.43 |
| C    | Z    |         100 | 27.03 |
+------+------+-------------+-------+
[yes I calculated these manually]
```

Kindly help me with correcting my query.

Comment: Provide sample data as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: In the subquery you must group by dept (and add it to the output list). In outer query use INNER JOIN by this dept column.

Comment: 1. Edit: added data to the question, you can simply copy paste in excel and import it to mysql.
2. This method doesn't return expected result, can you please help with correcting up the query.

Comment: `DESC TABLE` is NOT `CREATE TABLE` and cannot be used as SQL code. The same about data as a table - it cannot be used.